# monaca クイズアプリについて

Tags: javascript, monaca, css

http://matorel.com/archives/754
こちらのサイトも参考にしてクイズアプリを作ったのですが、いざandroidへダウンロードし試してみると、PC上だとできるのですが選択肢のボタンが改行されなくて横に伸びてしまいます。
よって選択肢のボタンが画面外へ行ってしまいます。

どうすればよろしいでしょうか？
LGL23を使用しております。

Answer (score 1):

実装はGitからプロジェクトをインポートしたのでしょうか？
リンクだけではなく問題のコードと、
スクショなどを質問文に記載なさると回答もつきやすいかと思います。

本題ですが、`<ons-row>`で`<ons-col>`とボタンを4つ纏めて括っているものを、2つずつで括ってはどうでしょうか？
おそらくMETAの記述がリンク先と違うので`ons-row`で指定した行が優先されて1行に纏められているものと思われます。